# compilation faild - Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources - Duplicate resources

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

i am getting this error while trying to run my app in android studio.
all the "duplicate" resources exist in different layout folders(each for different size).

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> [layout-ldrtl-hdpi-v17/coachmark_dashboard2] C:\Users\USER\Mobile-Android\app\src\main\res\layout-ldrtl-hdpi\coachmark_dashboard2.xml [layout-ldrtl-hdpi-v17/coachmark_dashboard2] C:\Users\USER\Mobile-Android\app\src\main\res\layout-ldrtl-hdpi-v17\coachmark_dashboard2.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
[layout-ldrtl-v17/coachmark_dashboard3] C:\Users\USER\Mobile-Android\app\src\main\res\layout-ldrtl\coachmark_dashboard3.xml [layout-ldrtl-v17/coachmark_dashboard3] C:\Users\USER\Mobile-Android\app\src\main\res\layout-ldrtl-v17\coachmark_dashboard3.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
[layout-ldrtl-v17/coachmark_dashboard4] C:\Users\USER\Mobile-Android\app\src\main\res\layout-ldrtl\coachmark_dashboard4.xml [layout-ldrtl-v17/coachmark_dashboard4] C:\Users\USER\Mobile-Android\app\src\main\res\layout-ldrtl-v17\coachmark_dashboard4.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
[layout-ldrtl-v17/coachmark_dashboard1] C:\Users\USER\Mobile-Android\app\src\main\res\layout-ldrtl\coachmark_dashboard1.xml [layout-ldrtl-v17/coachmark_dashboard1] C:\Users\USER\Mobile-Android\app\src\main\res\layout-ldrtl-v17\coachmark_dashboard1.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
[layout-ldrtl-v17/coachmark_dashboard2] C:\Users\USER\Mobile-Android\app\src\main\res\layout-ldrtl\coachmark_dashboard2.xml [layout-ldrtl-v17/coachmark_dashboard2] C:\Users\USER\Mobile-Android\app\src\main\res\layout-ldrtl-v17\coachmark_dashboard2.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
[layout-ldrtl-v17/coachmark_feed2] C:\Users\USER\Mobile-Android\app\src\main\res\layout-ldrtl\coachmark_feed2.xml   [layout-ldrtl-v17/coachmark_feed2] C:\Users\USER\Mobile-Android\app\src\main\res\layout-ldrtl-v17\coachmark_feed2.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
[layout-ldrtl-v17/coachmark_feed1] C:\Users\USER\Mobile-Android\app\src\main\res\layout-ldrtl\coachmark_feed1.xml   [layout-ldrtl-v17/coachmark_feed1] C:\Users\USER\Mobile-Android\app\src\main\res\layout-ldrtl-v17\coachmark_feed1.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
[layout-ldrtl-v17/coachmark_feed3] C:\Users\USER\Mobile-Android\app\src\main\res\layout-ldrtl\coachmark_feed3.xml   [layout-ldrtl-v17/coachmark_feed3] C:\Users\USER\Mobile-Android\app\src\main\res\layout-ldrtl-v17\coachmark_feed3.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
[layout-ldrtl-v17/coachmark_select_university] C:\Users\USER\Mobile-Android\app\src\main\res\layout-ldrtl\coachmark_select_university.xml   [layout-ldrtl-v17/coachmark_select_university] C:\Users\USER\Mobile-Android\app\src\main\res\layout-ldrtl-v17\coachmark_select_university.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
[layout-ldrtl-v17/coachmark_dashboard_box] C:\Users\USER\Mobile-Android\app\src\main\res\layout-ldrtl\coachmark_dashboard_box.xml   [layout-ldrtl-v17/coachmark_dashboard_box] C:\Users\USER\Mobile-Android\app\src\main\res\layout-ldrtl-v17\coachmark_dashboard_box.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
```

Answer (score 0):

there was a problem with layout-ldrtl folders.
in my case i changed it to layout-heb(hebrew), this work around works for me.